# parseInt in JavaScript or AS3 returning wrong value

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain why all these parseInt operations evaluate to the same number **10153593963283296**?

parseInt('10153593963283294')
10153593963283294

parseInt('10153593963283295')
**10153593963283296**

parseInt('10153593963283296')
**10153593963283296**

parseInt('10153593963283297')
**10153593963283296**

parseInt('10153593963283298')
10153593963283298

Tested in browsers and node command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's because you've reached the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.

Please, read this article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

There's a note:

"The reasoning behind that number is that JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754 and can only safely represent numbers between -(253 - 1) and 253 - 1.

Safe in this context refers to the ability to represent integers exactly and to correctly compare them."

Answer (score 4):

Your number is larger than [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). JavaScript stores even Integers as floating-point numbers and therefore you lose precision once your number becomes too large.